# How to give multiple layers to LSTM as timesteps in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to give two separate neural networks to an lstm as 2 timesteps. this is my code:

```
input1 = Input(shape=(self.state_size,1))
input2 = Input(shape=(self.state_size,1))

out1 = Conv1D(12, 5, padding="SAME", activation="relu")(input1)
out1 = Flatten()(out1)
out1 = Dense(12, activation="relu")(out1)

out2 = Conv1D(12, 5, padding="SAME", activation="relu")(input2)
out2 = Flatten()(out2)
out2 = Dense(12, activation="relu")(out2)

out = CuDNNLSTM(1)([out1,out2])
```

the error is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer cu_dnnlstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

which refers to:

```
out = CuDNNLSTM(1)([out1,out2])
```

I have also tried:

```
out = CuDNNLSTM(1)(out1,out2)
```

my input shape is (none,4,1) and I need my output shape to be (none,1). obviously the input shape for CuDNNLSTM has to be (none,2,12), but i have difficulty concatenating out1 and out2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to `stack` the tensors in the middle dimension:

```
steps = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack(x, axis=1))([out1, out2])
out = CuDNNSLTM(1)(steps)
```

But I'm not sure a sequence with two steps will bring great results that regular layers can't.